# Rust Ownership Challenges in Drawing Application: Need Assistance with Code Section

Tags: html, rust, canvas, yew

Trying to replicate the MNIST ONNX runtime [example](https://microsoft.github.io/onnxruntime-web-demo/#/mnist) on Yew rust. I found the code on github [github code](https://github.com/microsoft/onnxruntime-web-demo/blob/main/src/components/common/DrawingModelUI.vue#L287), I am stuck trying to replicate the drawing component.

I'm encountering difficulties with a specific section of my Rust code, particularly within the draw function. Below is the problematic segment:

```
 let draw = Callback::from(move |e: MouseEvent| {
        let mut canvas = canvas_node_ref.cast::<HtmlCanvasElement>();
        log::info!("draw");


        if let Some(canvas) = canvas {
            let ctx = match canvas.get_context("2d") {
                Ok(Some(ctx)) => ctx,
                _ => return,
            }
            .dyn_into::<web_sys::CanvasRenderingContext2d>()
            .unwrap();
        
            ctx.set_line_width(20.0);
            ctx.set_line_join("round");
            ctx.set_line_cap("round");
            ctx.set_stroke_style(&JsValue::from_str("#393E46"));
            ctx.clear_rect(0.0, 0.0, canvas.width() as f64, canvas.height() as f64);

            let strokes = draw_context_clone.state().strokes;
            //log::info!("the number of strokes is {}", strokes.len());
        let mut points = strokes.last().and_then(|p| Some(p.clone())).unwrap_or_else(|| Vec::new());
            points.push(math_utils::get_coordinates(e));
            let len = points.len();
            //log::info!("the size is {}", len);
        
            for s in 0..len-1 {
                points = strokes[0].clone();
                let p1 = points[s];
                let p2 = points[s + 1];
                log::info!("inside for loopp {}", p1.0);
                ctx.begin_path();
                ctx.move_to(p1.0 as f64, p1.1 as f64);
                let midpoint = math_utils::get_midpoint(p1, p2);
                ctx.quadratic_curve_to(p1.0 as f64, p1.1 as f64, midpoint.0 as f64, midpoint.1 as f64);
                ctx.stroke();   
            }
        }
    });

    let draw_clone = draw.clone();
    let activate_draw = Callback::from(move |e: MouseEvent| {
        log::info!("activate_draw");
        drawing.set(!*drawing); //= true;
        draw_context.new_stroke();
        let strokes = draw_context.state().strokes;

        //let mut points = strokes.last().unwrap().clone();
        let mut points = strokes.last().and_then(|p| Some(p.clone())).unwrap_or_else(|| Vec::new());
        log::info!("{}", points.len());
        points.push(math_utils::get_coordinates(e.clone()));
        draw_clone.emit(e);
    });
```

Here is how it is being used in the html elements

```
html! {
        <div>
            <div class="input-column">
            <div class="input-container">
              <div class="input-label">{"Draw any digit"}</div>
              <div class="canvas-container">
                <canvas
                  ref={canvas_node_ref_clone}
                  id="input-canvas"
                  width="300"
                  height="300"
                  onmousedown={activate_draw}
                  onmousemove={draw}
                ></canvas>
              </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    }
```

I've been grappling with Rust's ownership model, hence resorting to multiple clones. The issue arises specifically in this line:`let mut points = strokes.last().and_then(|p| Some(p.clone())).unwrap_or_else(|| Vec::new());`
Here, a new vector is created, causing the for loop within the draw function to never execute as expected.

Any insights or suggestions on how to address this issue would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: What's the problem exactly? Does the code fail to compile? With what error? Does the code compile but fail to run? With what error? Does the code compile and run but fail to provide the expected result? What did you expect and what happened instead?

Comment: I am expecting the ability to draw lines on a canvas HTML element with a mousedown event . I did some looking around, and narrowed down the issue with the way I am handling strokes. / points. When initiating the points by taking the last stroke it always defaults to creating a new vector. This is the case even when the strokes array is clearly not empty.